# Media-query max-width not functioning properly

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Good day everybody! I am currently working on a web app, and I am using media-queries, in aims to support mobile and desktop.

I have tried to use `max-width: 414px` as my first break-point, to work on the current iPhones and other phones with smaller screen sizes. However, even after rereading various forum posts, responsive web design tutorials, and web documentations, to no luck, it wouldn't work the way I need it to.

[image]

See here that whenever I use `max-width`, even on screen sizes of 414px, or lower (I have tried), it really wouldn't work. The styles wouldn't apply.

[image]

Now, when I would use, `min-width`, it does work, however, I've read it's better RWD practice to use `max-width` for better functionality.

[image]

What are your suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: suggestions??? code instead pictures

Comment: Did you add this `meta` to your HTML file ?

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: @JulienvanderKluft Yes :)

Comment: @dippas majority of my code si ply makes the form look like the picture below. I am quite certain that it is my implementation of max-width at problem... Please do correct me if I am wrong? :)

Comment: you are testing with retina 3x, test with retina 1x, and why not use a standard breakpoint such as 480px or 640px? Remember anyways the content should define the bp, not the other way around

Comment: I have tried sir (1x), and I have also tried 480px, however, max-width still doesn't work... @dippas

Comment: In fact, `min-width` of iPhone 6+ is 414px. So with a `max-width` to 414px, you don't reach the iPhone 6+ resolution.

Comment: change the breakpoint to 480px, it will work

Comment: @dippas, when I changed it to 960px, it works until 480px, and when I changed it to 1000px, it works until 500px....

Comment: @JulienvanderKluft What do you mean? :)

Comment: @dippas New development, now breakpoint is twice the amount of max-width...

Comment: Sorry, i talked a bit fast. But now, it's really look like you do not use this `<meta name="viewport">`. Can you try with `max-device-width` instead of `max-width`?

Comment: @JulienvanderKluft still doesn'5 work

Comment: We definitely need that you provide the problematic part of your code on a live example, like on Codepen or other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think your problem is that you are in zoom mode (like 2x or 3x). If you are in Safari responsive mode, please remember to go to use `View > Actual Size` , make sure it's not zoomed in in any way, as this will surely affect the media query used. Have a good day!